# How can i transfer data from an android device to a C++ PC program?

Tags: android, c++, bluetooth, connection

I want to connect an android mobile program to a C++ program, and i dont really know how it should be done.

I was thinking about a Bluetooth connection, but i dont really know how to handle bluetooth in C++. Could you give me some general advice about this?

If you think that i should use another kind of connection, like tpc-ip based, please, let me know and give me some general advices too.

I need the data transfer to be fast, because im trying to use the android device as an interactor, so i need a fast feedback from the C++ program.

Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would use a TCP/IP connection. It is very easy to implement in Java (Android) and also in C++. Besides, it makes it easy to change the frontend later on. And it is as fast as your network connection, which is usually faster than bluetooth.

Just make sure you put enough effort in the design of your protocol.

There are a lot of resources to be found on the internet on how to create TCP/IP connections, both in Java and C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to have a client server model kind of an use here. Better is to host your Server app(Port your C++ app to Java servlets) & access the Server app via http via Android client. Webviews in android are very useful in doing these.

Comment: I cant do that, becaise the c++ app cant be ported, it does intensive calculus and it needs to be in c++. Plus, i need it to be in c++, because other libraries used are only for c++